# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'get_Day()' method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

So I'm trying to create an Expression That does a DateTime Compare on the Day of a Paticular date specified through an expression. However I keep getting the Error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'get_Day()' method.

Get Day However is a able to be used with Entity Framework you can access the property and compare it fine if you build the lamba normally.

Normally It would complied down to sql something like

```
WHERE ((DATEPART (day, [Project6].[C1])) >= (DATEPART (day, '4/28/2015 12:00:00 AM')))
```

This is my function Does anyone know what I can do to fix this error?

```
public IQueryable<T> SetDateCompare<T>(IQueryable<T> OriginalQuery, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> getDateFunc, DateTime ComparisonDate, bool isGreaterThan = true)
where T : class
{
    if (isGreaterThan)
    {

        Expression left = Expression.Call(getDateFunc.Body, typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("get_Day"));
        Expression right = Expression.Constant(ComparisonDate.Day, typeof(int));
        Expression res = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);

        var whereCallLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(left, right), getDateFunc.Parameters.Single());

        MethodCallExpression whereCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
                                                                "Where",
                                                                new Type[] { OriginalQuery.ElementType },
                                                                OriginalQuery.Expression,
                                                                whereCallLambda);

        OriginalQuery = OriginalQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCall);
    }

    return OriginalQuery;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use [`SqlFunctions.DatePart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171) - that's basically the way of creating a query using `DATEPART` in the SQL.

Comment: My wish Came True I was hoping you'd reply.  So Do I call the SQLFunction.DatePart instead of get day? and would I do this twice then once for the Expression and the other time for the Comparison Date ?

Comment: @johnny5: I wouldn't bother doing it for the comparison date - after all, the day part of that is a constant, so you might as well *pass* it as a constant. You don't call `SqlFunctions.DatePart` directly - you build an expression tree that would call it, just as you're currently building an expression tree to call the `Day` property accessor.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public IQueryable<T> SetDateCompare<T>(IQueryable<T> OriginalQuery, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> getDateFunc, DateTime? ComparisonDate, bool isGreaterThan = true)
    where T : class
    {

            Expression right = Expression.Constant(ComparisonDate, typeof(DateTime?));
            var RightFunc = Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctions), "TruncateTime", null, right);

            //Expression left = Expression.Call(getDateFunc.Body, typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("get_Day"));
            //Expression res = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);

            Expression FuncToExec = isGreaterThan ?
                MyGreaterThanOrEqual(getDateFunc.Body, RightFunc) :
                 MyLessThanOrEqual(getDateFunc.Body, RightFunc);

            var whereCallLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(FuncToExec, getDateFunc.Parameters.Single());

            MethodCallExpression whereCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
                                                                    "Where",
                                                                    new Type[] { OriginalQuery.ElementType },
                                                                    OriginalQuery.Expression,
                                                                    whereCallLambda);

            OriginalQuery = OriginalQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCall);



        return OriginalQuery;

    }
 static Expression MyGreaterThanOrEqual(Expression e1, Expression e2)
    {
        if (IsNullableType(e1.Type) && !IsNullableType(e2.Type))
            e2 = Expression.Convert(e2, e1.Type);
        else if (!IsNullableType(e1.Type) && IsNullableType(e2.Type))
            e1 = Expression.Convert(e1, e2.Type);
        return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(e1, e2);
    }

    static Expression MyLessThanOrEqual(Expression e1, Expression e2)
    {
        if (IsNullableType(e1.Type) && !IsNullableType(e2.Type))
            e2 = Expression.Convert(e2, e1.Type);
        else if (!IsNullableType(e1.Type) && IsNullableType(e2.Type))
            e1 = Expression.Convert(e1, e2.Type);
        return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(e1, e2);
    }

    static bool IsNullableType(Type t)
    {
        return t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
    }
```

this is the working code thanks!